# AmazonS3Client.putObject with File keeps open reference to file

Tags: java, aws-sdk

We are working with AWS SDK S3 version 2.4.2 version for Java. When we are trying to put object (s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build(), Paths.get(file));) for multiple files with single connection, It is failing with "Too many open files" issue after uploading some thousands files. When we have checked in the unix machine with "pfiles" command with process ID, It is never closing the files reference, until the application is finished/killed.

Comment: Thats strange. If you look at the source code, you can see that it releases the resources.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!!!..We have tried to check the source code. But we couldn't figure out, where it is opening the file and releasing it. Could you help?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, we have ended up using file input stream with byte array and closed manually from our program:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = IoUtils.toByteArray(fis);
s3.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(key).build(), RequestBody.fromBytes(data));
data = null; 
fis.close();
```